# How to print the location of malware in the terminal with ClamAV?

Tags: malware, antivirus, clamav

When I use

```
clamscan -r --bell -i /
```

(scan the whole system, output only when warning appear)

I get this warning in the terminal

```
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
```

How can I get the location of the file?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `-i` and scan again. You will get a full list including the name of the file that shows this notice.

If you want even more info add the verbose and/or debug options.

Comment: this didnt work for me.. since it is a warning, it does not show as an error.. I reran clamav and > the output to a file until I saw the warnings (also have a scanxz size one), however it was neither are to be found in either that file or with the `-l` logfile. Since my purpose was quelling any ancilary output that Cronic sees as not passing without error, I ended up `grep -v` the keywords to remove them from the output. I would rather exclude the files. I found only one webpage where the warning was followed by the filename.. maybe it was using --debug.